# What blog services work well on Tor

Tags: deanonymization, information-leaks

I´ve tried to create blog accounts using Tor. They always fail at some point. For example:

- Wordpress: the confirmation mail doesn't include the link necessary to confirm.
- Ghost: I registered successfully, but all the features are missing in the menu list, so I can't post.

Which blog services works? I want to register with a mail2tor email account and dont want to give phone numer or any personal data.

Comment: Could you view the source of the mail? I've registered Wordpress accounts before and it always wrked. Maybe your mail client is hiding them?